# Is there a way to use column grouping in combination with autoColumns?

Tags: tabulator

I know how to pass a function to autoColumnsDefinitions to manipulate the column definition array, but I'm having trouble with dynamic column grouping. For example, say I get these fields:

```
te_all, te_d1, te_d2, te_d3, te_d4, te_d5, te_d6, te_d7, te_d8, te_d9, te_d10
```

I know how to format them the way I want, but I can't figure out how to group them under a column group with title "TOTAL EXPENDITURE" inside the autoColumnsDefinitions function. It needs to be dynamic because I might get that list, or I might get:

```
te_all, te_q1, te_q2, te_q3, te_q4, te_q5
```

which would also need to be grouped as "TOTAL EXPENDITURE". There are a set of these possibilities that I need to handle. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The grouped column definition needs to be inserted into the definitions array while removing the original columns.

```
definitions.splice(1, 11, {
    title:"TOTAL EXPENDITURES",
    columns:[
        {title:"ALL", field:"te_all"},
        {title:"D1", field:"te_d1"},
        {title:"D2", field:"te_d2"},
        {title:"D3", field:"te_d3"},
        {title:"D4", field:"te_d4"},
        {title:"D5", field:"te_d5"},
        {title:"D6", field:"te_d6"},
        {title:"D7", field:"te_d7"},
        {title:"D8", field:"te_d8"},
        {title:"D9", field:"te_d9"},
        {title:"D10", field:"te_d10"}
    ]
});
```